# line height higher in Firefox than IE and Chrome - default Firefox settings?

Tags: html, firefox, compatibility

The following code displays as desired in both IE and Chrome, but Firefox uses some default line height default that I am not able to override. So the line height is higher in Firefox, than in IE and Chrome. Does someone have some tip? Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

```
<table style="cellspacing:-200%;cellpadding:-200%;padding:-200%">
<tr style="cellspacing:-200%;cellpadding:-200%;padding:-200%">
<td style="cellspacing:-200%;cellpadding:-200%;padding:-200%">
<sup style="vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: -0.5em; font-size: 50%">1</sup><font style="font-size: 50%"> Test 01.</font><br>
<sup style="vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: -0.5em; font-size: 50%">2</sup><font style="font-size: 50%"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know the code is not the best, but as I am using inline styling, I believe it should also work get the same output in Firefox right?

Thanks everyone in advance, windomearle.

Comment: The browsers do seem to have a different default. Setting a line-height (like `line-height: 1`) has them display the same.

Comment: There is no attempt at setting line height at all in the code. It contains just some nonsensical CSS code and some code for vertical placement using *both* `vertical-align` *and* relative positioning. And there is no description of how it was inferred that some browser uses higher line height that some others. And no statement of how things *should* be.

Comment: @misterManSam: true, I used that <tag> line-height and it solved my problem, just posted the solution that worked for me below.

@ Jukka K. Korpela: you are right, I thought that cellpadding would solve the issue, but it didn't. the vertical align was to ensure that <sup> doesn't increase the size of the line itself. yes there is not, because I didn't share the printscreens. Still it was happening just like I described above. Things should be displayed the same in all browsers like I said. The issue is already solved, using http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/ you can Preview HTML code easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/ (in the below window you can see a Preview of the code itself) as a debugger, I used the following code and it worked for me. Basically the tag line-height: value solved the problem. Hope it is useful for someone! Have a good day!

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<sup style="vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: -0.15em; font-size: 45%; line-height: 4px">1</sup><font style="font-size: 49%; line-height: 6px"> Test 01.</font><br />
<sup style="vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: -0.15em; font-size: 45%; line-height: 4px">2</sup><font style="font-size: 49%; line-height: 6px"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</font>  
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks, windomearle